# NGINX directory files owned by root, is this behaviour normal?

Tags: nginx

while inspecting my nginx directory tree, I have found that all of the `/etc/nginx`, and so on is owned by **root**

[image: NGINX ROOT OWNERSHIP]

Is this a normal behaviour, should I run `chown -R nginx:nginx /etc/nginx` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a normal behaviour

Yes.

> should I run chown -R nginx:nginx /etc/nginx ??

No. The `nginx` user and group are for *worker* NGINX processes.

The master NGINX process starts as root so there's no problem having the configuration files owned as `root`.